# Out of Memory error while reading text file and adding into a list

Tags: java, arrays, file

I am trying to read a text file and adding each line to a list. The list is used in prepared statement to insert the records to db. The problem is when there is 1000000 records the execution becomes too slow and some time gets Out of Memory error.

My code

```
while ((sRec = in.readLine()) != null) {
        myCollection.add(reversePad(sRec, hmSizeLookup, colLength, tableName));
        a = Utility.getPositions(sRec, hmSizeLookup, colLength);
        i = i + 1;
}
for (int j = 0; j < a.length; j++) {
    Field f = (Field) hmSizeLookup.get(String.valueOf(j));
    sAllFields += f.getColumnName();
    if (j < a.length) {
        sValues += "?";
    }
    if (j < a.length - 1) {
       sValues += ",";
       sAllFields += ",";
    }
}
sQ = "insert  into " + tableName + "(" + sAllFields + ") values(" + sValues + ")";
ds1.executePreparedStatement(sQ, myCollection);
```

How can read only 1000 lines at a time from the text file and need to perform the insert operation ? This should continue until the end of text file.

Any suggestions are appreciated,

Thanks

Comment: You already told the solution. Reading only 1000 at a time. Just use a counter to achieve it.

Comment: i used it but only 1000 records got inserted, i need to read 1000 records every time until EOF

Comment: So do that, 1000 at a time. What's the question here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do the inserting in the file loop.

Chop the insert code out to a function, every 1000 lines call it and then myCollection.clear()

After the loop you'll need to call it again for any data after the last insert.

So something like:

```
int line = 0;
while ((sRec = in.readLine()) != null) {
        myCollection.add(reversePad(sRec, hmSizeLookup, colLength, tableName));
        a = Utility.getPositions(sRec, hmSizeLookup, colLength);
        i = i + 1;
    if (++line > 1000) {
        doTheInsert(myCollection);
        myCollection.clear();
        line = 0;
    }
}
doTheInsert(myCollection);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but myCollection contains list of collection like [[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4]....], i need to get the first 1000 lists from the mycollection. How to get that count ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is one of a million possible implementations:

```
String sRec = null;
READ_LINES:
do {
    for (int i = 0; (sRec = in.readLine()) != null && i < 1000;  i++) {
        myCollection.add(reversePad(sRec, hmSizeLookup, colLength, tableName));
        a = Utility.getPositions(sRec, hmSizeLookup, colLength);
    }
} while (sRec != null);
```

Comment: +1 for the line "Here is one of a million possible implementations"

Answer (score 1):

Pseudo code only as I'm leaving for work:

```
    int maxLines=1000;
    int currentLine=0;

    while ((sRec = in.readLine()) != null) {

      Add to collection
      Increment currentLine
      if currentLine % maxLnes == 0 {
         UpdateDB(collection)
         clear collection
         currentLine=0
      }

    }

updateDB(collection)  // catch any stragglers
```

Sorry about the lack of working code but the idea is sound and it looks like you know your way around java.